# How to save to current User\Desktop location

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to save an excel worksheet as a .PRN file to the current users desktop. I thought maybe there was a standard "wildcard" operator that I could use, but I don't see that anywhere. I have looked through stack overflow and I found information that is probably what I am looking for, but due to me not being a programmer and not very good with excel, I don't know if it is what I want and if it is, where to put it in my code.

This is what I am currently running that only works on my machine:

```
Sub Save_PRN()
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\PRN Test files\" & Range("'Customer_Info'!R2").Text & ".prn"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

While it does what I want, when I upload it to our share, clearly another user won't be able to use it. I saw on a question someone answered stating to use this:

```
MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
```

But I don't know or understand how to incorporate that into my macro above. Any help or advice would be great. Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 6):

While roryap's solution is perfectly fine and working, I would like to add another working solution.

```
Dim strPath as String
strFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\PRN Test files\" & Range("'Customer_Info'!R2").Text & ".prn"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a difference in functionality? @roryap suggestion worked just fine as you stated. Is one way better than the other? If I can avoid errors down the road, I would like to, as this is the last project I am working on with this company and I don't want them to get screwed.

Comment: If it has to be stored on the desktop then roryap's solution is slightly better because the desktop folder does not always have to be stored within the user profile. It can actully be somewhere else located and / or made available offline and the underlying linked server becomes the path. Within a Citrix environment and a server-farm it gets even a bit more complicated. Therefore, I normally prefer the designated areas to store stuff which is usually `Environ("TEMP")` for temporary files or `Environ("HOMESHARE")` or `Environ("HOMEPATH")`. But for desktop I'd stick with roryap's solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use it like this:

```
Dim desktopFolderPath As String
desktopFolderPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
fileName = desktopFolderPath & "\PRN Test files\" & Range("'Customer_Info'!R2").Text & ".prn"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to 'tokenize' these standard folders as symbols that can substituted for the standard folder path when you save the data, and expanded into the next machine's locally-defined special folders when the data is read again.

I'm not aware of any universally-accepted set of tokens (labels, names, abbreviations or vulgar imprecations) for this: I'd be grateful if someone could enlighten me if there is, because this is a very common task and I hate reinventing the wheel.

The beautifully-carved square wheels below will make an interesting conversation piece for your apartment and a clunky solution to your problem: all you have to do is save the path down through the 'Substitute' function below, **every time you capture and save a folder path to your data store**...

...And read the path using the 'Expand' function **every time you retrieve a folder path from your data store and use it to open a folder**.

Clunk, clunk, clunk: it's the distinctive sound of the newly-invented 'Wheel' in motion. I have some really interesting designs for a thermonuclear mousetrap up on the Excellerando Blogspot, too: search for the term 'Horrible Hack'.

`Public Function SubstituteStandardFolders(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Insert abbreviations for standard folders 

Dim strUser     As String
Dim strDesk     As String
Dim strAppD     As String
Dim strDocs     As String
Dim strTemp     As String 

strDesk = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
strDocs = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
strAppD = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("AppData")
strTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2)
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName 

strPath = Replace(strPath, strDesk, "[Desktop]", , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, strDocs, "[My Documents]", , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, strAppD, "[Application Data]", , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, strTemp, "[Temp]", , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, strUser, "[User]", , , vbTextCompare) 

SubstituteStandardFolders = strPath 

End Function 


Public Function ExpandStandardFolders(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Replace abbreviations for standard folders with their full names 

Dim strUser     As String
Dim strDesk     As String
Dim strAppD     As String
Dim strDocs     As String
Dim strTemp     As String 

strDesk = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
strDocs = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
strAppD = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("AppData")
strTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2)
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName 

strPath = Replace(strPath, "[Desktop]", strDesk, , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, "[My Documents]", strDocs, , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, "[Application Data]", strAppD, , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, "[Temp]", strTemp, , , vbTextCompare)
strPath = Replace(strPath, "[User]", strUser, , , vbTextCompare) 

ExpandStandardFolders = strPath 

End Function`

Note the 'Hail Mary' clause at the end: if all else fails, swap out the user name for [User] and hope that the path is constructed the same way on all the other machines.

There are limitations to this code. Look at the list of tokens:

`[Desktop]         
 [My Documents]    
 [Application Data]
 [Temp]            
 [User]`

If you enumerate the Shell SpecialFolders collection, you'll see that there are more than that:

`Public Sub EnumerateSpecialFolders() 

Dim objCollection As Object
Dim varX As Variant 

Set objCollection = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders  

For Each varX In objCollection
    Debug.Print varX
Next varX 

End Sub`

However, I can't get the keys out of that collection - just the values - and the ordinals will vary from system to system.

If you could get the keys, that'd be a reasonable set of tokens for universal use. Assuming, of course, that 'My Documents' isn't retrieved by the key 'MiaDocumetari' or a string of two- and three-byte unicodes on half the workstations in your company.

Also: welcome to Deep VBA. It's the trivial tasks that require square-wheel workarounds, and I have a sneaking suspicion that our colleagues in more widely-respected languages are shielded from this by absurdly-overcomplicated bodges in their SDK developer libraries: these workarounds originate in bad design decisions at the OS level and nobody's actually 'solving' them.