# VBA Code does not always save in desktop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code in most cases will save to the desktop, but sometimes when I am connected to the network, it will save into a network folder. I am keen for this to always save it in my desktop in all cases.

```
Sub Svas()

Dim Name As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop": Name = "ETC & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I am not a strong coder, and an example or any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [How to save to current User\Desktop location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895486/how-to-save-to-current-user-desktop-location)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are saving the file with filename set to your 'File' string variable, which doesn't include the filepath- Try something like the following where you break the filePath, fileName and fileExt into 3 separate parts to help keep it organized and then you can easily concatenate them at the end to create the full filename and path.

```
Sub Svas()
Dim fName As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim fExt As String
fPath = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop" 'Code for filepath
fName = "ETC" 'Code for filename
fExt = ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fPath & "\" & fName & fExt, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Answer (score 0):

After the last folder in your path, you need to add `\` before the file name.
In your case, you need to add `"\Desktop\"`.

Since you are using "ETC" in your code, not sure you need another variable for this code, and you could use something like the code below:

```
Sub Svas()

Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\ETC.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3287522 have you tried the answer above ? did it work for you ?

Comment: Hi Every one thank you so much, for your comments, I will try this when I go back into work, have not tried them, to see if this saves in my desktop rather than the networks